# OpenProcessToken fails when querying process running as NETWORK SERVICE

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke

I have code which  needs to query the process token (specifically the SID) of several processes, at least one of which is running as the built-in NETWORK SERVICE account.  I'm using .NET to get the process ID, and then p/invoke to advapi32 methods to open the process and the token.  All of this code runs as an administrator on the machine.

The issue is that I get ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED (return code 5) from OpenProcessToken every time.

What am I doing wrong?  This must be possible (for example, Process Explorer shows the SID and other token information of the target process), so I figure I'm missing something.  One thought is that perhaps I need SeDebugPrivilege. (EDIT: Doesn't work -- doing Process.EnterDebugMode to set SeDebugPrivilege on the current thread doesn't change behavior).

My code looks like this:

```
Process[] procs = Process.GetProcessesByName("processname");

Process process = procs[0];

IntPtr processHandle = NativeMethods.OpenProcess(
    ProcessAccessFlags.QueryInformation, 
    false, 
    process.Id);

if (
    !NativeMethods.OpenProcessToken(
        processHandle, 
        (uint)(TokenAccessLevels.Read), 
        out tokenHandle))
{
    int err = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

    // fails with err = 5
    throw new Win32Exception(err, "Failed to get process token. Error: " + err);
}
```

Note: I have tried a few other combinations of the access flags on both native calls, including using the PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS.

EDIT: One additional point, querying the same process running as a local limited-access user works fine.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? I have a similar issue I'm trying to solve, wherein my call to OpenProcessToken() always returns 0;